# Cursor not executing; dying without throwing an error

Tags: python, database

My code is, for some reason (which I'll figure out later), not throwing any errors, anywhere. For now, this code only runs till the `cursor.execute (...`, and dies.

I've considered scope and tried recreating a database connection and cursor in this function; didn't work. I know it executes till the said statement with 'print' statements.

```
def get_state_count(user_id, state_code):
    query_string = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM mytable WHERE state_code = %s AND usr_id = %s"
    query_params = (state_code, user_id)

    cursor.execute(query_string, query_params)
    result = cursor.fetchone()

    return result[0]
```

This is really simple code and all it's supposed to do is return a number. What it does, is die on the 'cursor.execute (query_string, query_params)' statement.

Comment: What database library are you using? In other words, where is `cursor` coming from?

Comment: I'm using postgresql / psycopg2. I've run the same statement, with values, in psql, and it works fine.

Comment: How do you declare the `execute`?

Comment: I didn't understand that @frankegoesdown. Could you rephrase please? If it's relevant, I'm using the same cursor just prior to calling this function, in another function, and it works fine there.

Comment: @SidKhullar expression like `cursor = conn.cursor()`

Comment: @frankegoesdown LOL, exactly that. :)

`DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']`

`conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')`

`cursor = conn.cursor()`

Comment: This particular snippet of code looks OK to me. If you can construct a [mcve], complete with whatever commands are necessary to create and populate `mytable`, I'd be happy to investigate the problem further.

Comment: Thank you @Kevin. This is however the exact code I'm using, and all of it. I've only changed the table name, which too follows the same pattern as the actual table. Does that help?

Comment: If this is the exact code you're using, and all of it, that explains the problem -- functions don't do anything unless they're called. Running the exact code in your post will perform no action and produce no output.

Comment: Okay. I didn't answer your question completely. This script runs on the cloud, uses webhooks etc., listens to a live data stream and logs them. Each log entry record has a user ID and a state code. It would be quite a task to create an example, a minimal one even, to reproduce table population.

The point of this function was to count how many state codes of a particular type exist for a given user ID.

Comment: The actual code has one more element - print statements between every line of code. When this function is called, each of those statements print, and stop printing just before `cursor.execute (...`.

Comment: I have a feeling that some part of your code or environment is catching exceptions and silencing them. Python doesn't usually die without explaining why. Try putting `raise Exception("Intentionally crashed")` at the top of your function. If you run your program and don't see a stack trace, then something is silencing your exceptions.

Comment: @Kevin Thank you. There was no stack trace, and nothing happened in the function ; i.e. the debug print statements didn't execute.

Comment: I do think time would be better spent on figuring out why there are no exceptions thrown, than spending so much (this isn't the first) time on visualising every error. I think I'll do that now. Thank you for the push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding quotes around the parameters solved this, strangely.

`query_string = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM botlog WHERE usr_id = '%s' AND state_code = '%s'"`

and changing

`cursor.execute (query_string % query_params)`